# QT - QTreeView - Custom Contact List

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, interface

I'm trying to maddle in QT for learning purposes.

I've looked through and read the QT Book from Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield and a view online tutorials.

I want to customize the interface of a chat program and therefor am trying to learn all about
the paint event, stylesheets and qstyle

I'm trying to make something like this for the contact List:

[image: List]

But I dont know how i should start out to do this.

I guess QTableView would be the way to go.

Should i replace the StandardTreeViewItem with a custom one for the active item or should i work with delegates?! I'm kind of lost here.

Every help is very welcome!
No matter if it is pointing in a direction or a more direct help.

Thanks in advance =)

**Where should i start to look in order to be able to make a nice custom contact List using C++ and QT?**

Comment: Take a look at QToolBox.

Comment: Does it mean I should post it as an answer?